# I can't make a foreign key filter

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a model that has a key of itself, indicating whether it is a sub category or a larger category.

```
class Categoria(TranslatableModel):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        nome=models.CharField(max_length=255),
        icone=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True),
    )

    categoria=models.ForeignKey(
        'Categoria',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='categorias'
    ),

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Categoria {}'.format(self.nome)
```

I would like to get the ones that don't have a category to indicate that they are parent categories

but it generates this error:

`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'categoria' into field. Choices are: id, produtotranslation, translations`

I tried to use a common filter but it generates the error above

```
categorias = Categoria.objects.filter(categoria__isnull=True)
```

The error code displayed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pedro/development/marcommerce/loja/views.py", line 22, in categories
    categorias = Categoria.objects.filter(categoria__isnull=True)
  File "/home/pedro/development/marcommerce/env_project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pedro/development/marcommerce/env_project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1421, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/pedro/development/marcommerce/env_project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1439, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/pedro/development/marcommerce/env_project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1446, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/pedro/development/marcommerce/env_project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1532, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/pedro/development/marcommerce/env_project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1562, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "/home/pedro/development/marcommerce/env_project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1407, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "/home/pedro/development/marcommerce/env_project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1217, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "/home/pedro/development/marcommerce/env_project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1709, in names_to_path
    raise FieldError(
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'categoria' into field. Choices are: id, produtotranslation, translations
```

Answer (score 0):

You need pass field name of ForeignKey

in `categoria` model have three fields

`id`, `produtotranslation`, `translations`

So, you can pass in Query any field name from above three fields names like this...

```
Categoria.objects.filter(categoria__id__isnull=True)

--------------- OR --------------

Categoria.objects.filter(categoria__produtotranslation__isnull=True)

--------------- OR --------------

Categoria.objects.filter(categoria__translations__isnull=True)
```

Comment: the error still persists, the same message

Comment: plz add error in comment